# Why can't I sign in to OneNote 2016 (64-bit)?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-onenote, windows-live, microsoft-onenote-2016

I am trying to get my computer to sign on to 64-bit OneNote 2016 on Win 7.

While the popup window shows up fine, when I input my credentials and although I get no error messages, I get another identical popup asking me to sign in.

I have tried this for two separate accounts both of which sign in fine on the OneNote website on my browsers. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I can't try the 32-bit version as I have 64-bit Office installed.

All "official" answers on MS forums seem to be vague and unhelpful. The only real conclusion is that it's only a OneNote 2016 problem, so if anyone has a link to an earlier version I'd also take that.

Comment: This sounds like a SSL problem.  Can you log into the account through a browser on the machine in question?

Comment: Yes, I already said so - I'll edit to make it clearer just in case.

Comment: @surfmadpig Have you tried clearing credential manager from control panel ?

Comment: @pun, there are no credentials listed there.

Comment: Is there any firewall blocking it perhaps? Are you using a pirate copy perhaps ? If you purchased it you're entitled to tech support, if it's pirate that could very well be the reason it's not working (i.e. it might be patched to block communication with MS)

Comment: @Florian: No firewall. I'm trying to use the free copy from the official website. This issue is rather widespread, considering the numerous questions I've found on official forums, I just can't find a solution to it.

Comment: Is this a personal account or a work/school account?

Comment: If it is a work account call your sysadmin.  If it is personal you may try calling Microsoft sup to see if they can unlock it.  It may just need a password reset or something of the sort.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC The account is not locked. I can sign in fine on their web page. Please read my question more carefully.

Comment: "or something of the sort."  I keep seeing this question and wonder if you have tried contacting the SysAdmin yet?  My guess this is an AD account and it just could have some sort of right's issue going on or something that no one here would ever be able to diagnose.  Because we don't have right s to the server.

Comment: Recently ,  Microsoft released some updates on windows 7, please install them , lets us see problem persists

Comment: @MusselmanLLC. There is no SysAdmin here, it's my effing personal laptop logged into an admin account.

Comment: "I can sign in fine on their web page." <-- Then what did you login to here?

Comment: I **am** the system administrator at my work and we have several users who can't sign in to OneNote with the same problem and symptoms. I'm not sure why so many unhelpful comments were posted here. If I figure out the problem I will add an answer here.

Comment: Hm. My problem was that I was trying to launch "OneNote" instead of "OneNote 2016". Seems like you are having a different problem.

Comment: could you link to the 'official' answer on MS forums?

Comment: anyone tried this: http://www.onenotegem.com/faqs/how-to-fix-stuck-in-onenote-2016-sign-in-loop?

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if it was luck, voodoo or pure logic, but I found a fix.  I too could not login to ONE PC for weeks.  However, I was able to login to other PC's fine.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling One-Note several times to no avail. So, my last try was to delete One-note from the hard drive and then copy some big files to the PC in hopes that those files would fill up that area on the hard drive so One Note would be forced to install on a different area of the hard drive.  I'll be darned that it worked!!!  Try it before pulling all your hair out!